# Implement scroll option ina a div with button scrolling feature

Tags: jquery, css, button, scroll

recently I tried to handle with a function http://jsfiddle.net/junglized/vJdCD/,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".page_up").click(function() {
        if (contentPage > 1) {
            contentPage--;
            $(".pageContent").animate({
                "margin-top" : "+=160px"
            }, "fast",function() {
                    setPageArrows();
                });
        }
    });

    $(".page_down").click(function() {
        if (contentPage < contentPages) {
            contentPage++;
            $(".pageContent").animate({
                "margin-top" : "-=160px"
            }, "fast",function() {
                    setPageArrows();
                });
        }
    });

    setPageArrows();
});
```

but I have no idea how add mouse scroll option uing css only. Adding overflow: auto; property i usable only when div is at it's top position. When I scroll down using added button possibility of using mouse to scroll disappears. Anybody any ideas? is it necessary to use jQuery in this task?

BTW, I need to get rid of the croll bar and leave ony buttons and mouse scroll.

---

EDIT

Nevermind, I used jScrollPane plugin to achieve desired effect. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the behavior you're looking for. If you do `overflow: hidden`, does it do what you want?

Comment: No, because mouse scroll is lost completely with overflow:hidden, I just need to scrol with buttons and mouse as well with above configuration, if you looked into the fiddle I posted you should know what I mean. Like I said, when I scroll down using button scrolling up with mouse wheel is impossible in current condition. I need to change it but I don't exactly know how. maybe there isa plugin somewhere which covers both of my expectations?